# openFDA: 510k update frequency

Tags: openfda

How often is openFDA 510k database updated?
Through the FDA website I see a new batch of 510k clearances from June 2016. However, openFDA has not been updated since May.

Answer (score 1):

The dataset was updated on March 6, 2017.  The updates occur from time to time without a planned update schedule. The latest updates for the 510K and other datasets are posted [here](https://open.fda.gov/api/status/).

Comment: can you provide more information please? how you know that/where you found that, etc.?

Comment: It also does not answer *how often*.

Comment: I'm one of the many folks working on Open FDA (https://open.fda.gov/about/). Unfortunately, I'm unable to answer "how often" at this point. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: Do you know when the previous update was? That would give at least some indication on the historic update interval.

Comment: Please see https://open.fda.gov/api/status/